# What's the easiest way to search for refundable air tickets?

Tags: air-travel, refunds

To satisfy onward ticket requirements every once in a while I need to buy refundable tickets and then cancel them.

Date, price and destination don't matter.

What is the best generic way to find such tickets out of any country?

Comment: Go to the website of a major airline operating in that country and search for a ticket to anywhere?

Comment: Some airlines don't show refundable fares online if there's a cheaper non-refundable fare available. I had this problem before with Transaero in Russia. The only solution I could find was to call the airline, talk to some very surprised agents, and spend about 45 minutes on hold - but I did get my refundable ticket at the end!

Comment: Generally speaking, the higher price of the flight ticket (in same level of seat), the less cost to refund it is

Comment: Call the airline and solicitation a refundable toll. It is normally higher than a non-refundable admission. Make certain to inquire as to whether there are any charges on the off chance that you choose to cross out the ticket.

Comment: If price doesn't matter, don't get refundable tickets.  You can get a refund on almost any ticket, and refundable tickets will overall be a waste of your money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in a [recent question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59239/difference-between-onwardflights-com-and-flyonward-com), there are now two companies dedicated to that exact need:

1. [OnwardFlights.com](http://www.onwardflights.com/)
2. [FlyOnward.com](https://flyonward.com/)
3. [BestOnwardTicket.com](https://bestonwardticket.com/)

According to a [review](https://nomadforum.io/t/do-you-always-have-an-onward-air-ticket-when-entering-a-new-country/915/36):

> I used both. Onwardflights.com photoshops tickets, Flyonward.com books real tickets. Onwardflights is cheaper for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Buy it with expedia.com and you gonna have 24 hours to get a full refund with no hassle via the website.

Comment: Are you sure about that, are absolutely all flights bought there refundable ? Could you expand your answer with some info from their policy perhaps ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've already done it several times. Any purchase at Expedia.com gives you the right of getting a full refund within 24 hours. Just go there, simulate any trip and you'll see next to the confirmation button a reminder saying it's free. but remember to do it with expedia.com. I've already checked the policies of expedia.de in example and it's different.

Comment: It's the law that tickets to or from the US booked at least a week ahead are refundable within 24 hours.