# What are the cheapest ways to get a flight booking out of China needed for my visa application from here in Mexico City?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, proof-of-onward-travel, travel-agents, mexico-city

I've been in Mexico for a month and a half and I'm currently heading to Mexico City to apply for a Chinese visa since I already have a flight back to China but my previous visa expired.

China requires a minimum of three bookings to issue a visa: One flight to China, One flight out of China, and one accommodation booking. Even if you intend to enter and/or leave via a land border and even if you're applying for a double-entry visa you only need show these reservations for the first entry.

Previously I have done this in Laos and Australia. In Vientiane one travel agent understood exactly what I needed and made the bookings, printed them out, then cancelled them for just a few dollars. In Australia a friend who worked as a travel agent at the time booked my flights and sent me the bookings before cancelling them.

In Mexico City I don't have such a friend and where you can walk around every travel agency in Vientiane in less than an hour, Mexico City is one of the biggest cities in the world.

I know I can book some kind of flight with no or low cancellation fee myself but don't know how to find such flights. There might be other ways I never thought of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not the first to use this type of hack and there do now exist websites to provide this service for just a few dollars:

- [Flyonward](https://flyonward.com/en/) books you onward tickets for 10 USD and automatically cancels them after 48h (you can ask for a quote if you need more than 48h).
- [Onwardlflights](http://www.onwardflights.com/) does the same for 7 USD but I don't see how long they take until cancellation of the ticket.

(Some countries do check whether bookings are still active before issuing a visa, so it may make a difference.) I have not used either website and am not affiliated. Tip of the hat to [youhavebeenupgraded](http://youhavebeenupgraded.boardingarea.com/2017/01/weiterflugtickets-mieten-und-den-letzten-flug-verfallen-lassen/) (in German).

Comment: Both of these sites seem to accept payment only via PayPal. That's worth including in the answer.

Comment: I've gone ahead and used onwardflights. Only after paying did I find that i will be sent the ticket within 48 hours. I was hoping to be able to go to the embassy today. Can anybody see how long FlyOnward takes to send you the ticket?

Comment: @hippietrail "Your e-tiket [sic!] will be emailed through to you within 8 hours of making payment by Paypal." from [their how-it-works](http://www.onwardflights.com/how-it-works). Also please go ahead and edit this info in.

Comment: Oops in my head I upgraded it from 8 to 48 hours! Result is the same that I'll miss the embassy though.

Comment: By the way we have a question on the site comparing these two services: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59239

Answer (score 1):

I just found out about another service online which is totally free of charge, **[returnFlights.net](http://www.returnflights.net/)**

> An Iraqi guy who lives in Germany told me that he's been using it
>   recently without problems.
>
> The site has a form you fill out with flight details you fond
>   yourself. It lists some points you should follow too:
>
> - Do not fly back to your country. The person at the check-in counter
>     might be suspicious because return flights with the same air carrier
>     are normally cheaper.
> - Do not choose the same airline for your onward ticket. They might
>     check it at the check-in counter..
> - Make sure you enter a valid flight and flight dates/time. Check here
>     for valid flight dates.
> - Once you printed out your flight ticket.
>     Highlight your name and flight destination with a marker. The person
>     on the check-in counter will appreciate it and will not check further
>     details.
>
> You also can additionaly write some address and phone number on the
>   paper to make it look more real.