# Get into a country without booked flight

Tags: air-travel, visa-refusals

In plenty of countries you can only enter if you can show a flight within your visa time out of the country.
There is the service flyonward.com. But it takes some days to get your ticket and it cost 10$.

Do you have any better proposals?

Comment: Why don't you have a return flight booked?  If we know the reason, it might be easier to help.

Comment: Relevant: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88746/what-are-the-cheapest-ways-to-get-a-flight-booking-out-of-china-needed-for-my-vi

Answer (score 1):

Really that is exactly what that service is for. It is cheap and offers people a way to show proof of travel for their return when they do not have one.

The easiest way not to need that service is to actually have a proof of return such as:

- A fully refundable return ticket or even ticket to any other outside destination. What countries want is to know when you are leaving, so you can look for the cheapest fare out of the country which is not usually a ticket home.
- Reservation on terrestrial transport leaving the country. If you are travelling to a country with land borders shared by other countries, you can find train and buses that leave the country and look to see if it is possible to make a reservation at little or no costs.